# Automatically inserting a value depending on dropdown choice

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am using an excel sheet to automate the process of calculating fiber dataloss.

The problem I have is the following:

I am using the values in the "Soorten Vezels" part of this sheet to generate a dropdown menu in another part of the worksheet. To keep this excel file really customizable, I want to be able to add a new type of fibre and then just add the max allowed loss next to it.

[image: Soorten Vezels]

Somewhere else in this sheet, I will be able to choose the type of fibre in a dropdown menu and then the excel sheet will automatically enter the max loss ( the one next to it in the pre-made list) in another field next to it.

I hope I have made this clear enough

Edit:

By using this:

```
=OPZOEKEN([Type kabel];Tabel3[#alles])
```

with "type kabel"  will be the value wich I am looking for in tabel3 and this works.
However, if I do the same in another field:

```
=OPZOEKEN(Tabel1[Type Connector];Tabel5[#alles])
```

it gives me the error:

```
#N/B
```

What Is wrong?

Comment: It does seem to work so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Vlookup function for that.

```
=vlookup(a1,Sheet2!$A$3:$B$9,2,False)
```

... where A1 is the cell with the drop-down value. Depending on your layout, you could build a dynamic range name for the data validation list and the lookup table, so you don't have to change your formula every time you add a new "Soorten Veezels".  For the data validation list use the named range LookupList with a formula like

```
=Sheet2!$A$3:INDEX(Sheet2!$A$3:$A$9,MATCH("zzzz",Sheet2!$A$3:$A$9,1))
```

For the lookup table use the name LookupTable with the formula

```
=offset(LookupList,0,0,,2)
```

Then you can use =LookupList as the reference for the drop-down and use the vlookup like this

```
=vlookup(A1,LookupTable,2,false)
```

Comment: I get the following error: #N/B